# What the X stands for in the front of Elliptic curve names like X25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, standards, notation

I have seen Curve25519 and X25519, Curve448 and X448. I've seen a small note in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68129/18298)

> (Historical note: Originally, X25519 was called Curve25519, but now Curve25519 just means the elliptic curve and X25519 means the cryptosystem.)

- Is it a standard to say CurveABC is the Elliptic Curve and XABC is the cryptosystem?
- Or, it is just a convention between the Elliptic Curve Cryptographers.

Comment: Note: This is an example to show how to ask a question for this [broad question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84430/18298)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an open standard by [IETF.org](https://www.ietf.org/)

We can find the details in the mail [archive of IETF](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/-9LEdnzVrE5RORux3Oo_oDDRksU/), D. J. Bernstein's response;

> It has become increasingly common for "Curve25519" to refer to an
> elliptic curve, while the original paper defined "Curve25519" as an
> X-coordinate DH system using that curve. "Ed25519" unambiguously refers
> to an Edwards-coordinate signature system using that curve.
>
> Kenny and others in Toronto recommended changing terminology to clearly
> separate these three items. Let me suggest the following terminology:
>
> - "**X25519**" is the recommended Montgomery-X-coordinate DH function.
> - "**Ed25519**" is the recommended Edwards-coordinate signature system.
> - "**Curve25519**" is the underlying elliptic curve.
>
> All relevant coordinate systems already have standard names in the
> literature, and I would suggest sticking to those names whenever it's
> necessary to discuss the coordinate systems per se: [...]

Bolds are mine.

Comment: Thanks to Squeamish Ossifrage for directing the link.

Comment: I thought before reading this answer, that **X** stood for the **X** as in DH Key e**X**change, since **X25519** is the cryptosystem developed using that particular curve Curve25519 !!!

Comment: @VivekanandV Schrödinger's cat. Until the author's intent is not known all are valid :). X X-coordinate, Ed  Edwards-coordinate. consistent. But revealed. The cat is living :)

Comment: @kelalaka thanks for the answer, it is the kind of insight I was looking for in in the broad question you linked in your comment.

Comment: @ams hope you got my point. A good question has your (single or very related) problem(s), what you see here and there (wiki, or the www) then your understanding/confusion,... correct tags and a good title ( not broad one, too), then post and wait.