# How to recover y-coordinates when using XZ montgomery curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, montgomery-ladder

I am using Montgomery ladder with Montgomery curve $by^2=x^3+ax^2+x$ using XZ coordinates and I recovered the $X$ value using $X3=X1/Z1$, but I don't know how to recover the $Y$ coordinates.

for Double and add ladder I am using this:

```
      A = X2+Z2
      AA = A2
      B = X2-Z2
      BB = B2
      E = AA-BB
      C = X3+Z3
      D = X3-Z3
      DA = D*A
      CB = C*B
      X5 = Z1*(DA+CB)2
      Z5 = X1*(DA-CB)2
      X4 = AA*BB
      Z4 = E*(BB+a24*E)
```

I tried this way :

```
x3=2;
y3 = mod(mod((x3.^3 + mod(a*x3.^2,p)+x3),p) * mod(modinvr(b,p),p),p);

for y = 0:22
    x = mod(y^2, 23);
    if x == y3
        fprintf("y = %d\n", y);// here I got two values of y 8 and 15
    end
end
```

here I got two values of y 8 and 15 both are correct points on the curve but in my case I want to choose `8` because the affine scalar point is `(2,8)` I have another point on the curve `(2,15)` but not in my scalar point! so that's why I need to select `8` instead of `15`.

Comment: Have you tried solving the curve equation for $y$?

Comment: I tried but it gives me 2 y coordinates but dont know how to choose the correct one

Comment: @swineone I tried this `%y3=(x+X1/Z1)[(X1+x*Z1)(X2+x*Z2)+(x^2+y)(Z1*Z2)](x*Z1*Z2)^-1+y` but it doesn't give me the correct value?

Comment: @swineone I edited with my trial

Comment: Being a quadratic equation, there are indeed 2 possible solutions. I’m a little rusty on my elliptic curves, but either both are valid, or your standard should specify a disambiguation rule: say, always take the positive value, or a value with some other property.

Comment: @swineone that rule i am trying to figure it out or there is a different equation for it

Answer (score 4):

Although [x25519](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84434/18298) uses only the x-coordinate for the DH, for some protocols the $y$ coordinate is also required. So, if one wants to find the $y$ coordinate of $[n]P$, where $P=(x_1,y_1)$ is in affine coordinates, there is a paper for finding $y_n=Y_n/Z_n$ from $x_1,y_1$, and $x_n$;

- 2001, [Efficient Elliptic Curve Cryptosystems from a Scalar Multiplication Algorithm with Recovery of the y-Coordinate on a Montgomery-Form Elliptic Curve](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44709-1_12.pdf), Katsuyuki Okeya and Kouichi Sakurai. The paper is not paywalled.

Given the [Montgomery curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) $$M_{A,B}:By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 +x$$
The result simply is;

$$y_n = \frac{(x_nx_1+1)(x_n+x_1+2A)-2A-(x_n-x_1)^2x_{n+1}}{2By_1}$$

Yes, it is $x_{n+1}$, and for that one needs to go for $[n+1]P$.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend seeing section 4.3 on [Montgomery curves and their arithmetic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/212.pdf) by Craig Costello and Benjamin Smith. It cites the document from the answer above but also explains, has the algorithm and the closed form while giving some "history" on the recovery of y.

Comment: We prefer self-contained answers to mere link to references. But your reference is extremely relevant!